# Seen any good early-bird sites with useful resources and code for O3D?

Tags: o3d

Looking for anything code-wise or even feedback on using/writing for Google Chrome's [O3D](http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/)?
It exposes Directx/OpenGL to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Google code has a directory of examples for it:

http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/docs/samplesdirectory.html

It also had a developer's guide:

http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/docs/devguideintro.html

Answer (score 0):

I bet you could get some feedback on the [discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/o3d-discuss?pli=1).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at my blog - I have put up a [series of tutorials on O3D](http://www.smokycogs.comyr.com/titanium-tutorials/)